# Filter on multiple columns and compile value to main workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple workbooks for each date e.g. Workbook_20230505 with data as below:

| Staff ID | Time | Staff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 34565 | 9:00:35 AM | SYSTEM |
| 23586 | 5:32:05 AM | SYSTEM |
| 46354 | 4:15:35 AM | ALEX |
| 46546 | 4:09:30 AM | CLARE |
| 98744 | 2:54:18 AM | JOHN |
| 34534 | 3:23:10 AM | SANDY |
| 87675 | 4:32:09 AM | MANDA |
| 35645 | 7:15:23 AM | VOID |
| 23423 | 6:15:23 AM | ALEX |
| 23423 | 3:46:15 AM | KEN |
| 34564 | 7:08:23 AM | KEAT |

I am able to compile the latest time given criteria (where Staff <> "SYSTEM" or "VOID") to a main workbook as below:

**Update:** The Date column has all the days of the month, but not all days there is a workbook. If there is no workbook for that day, leave the result at Latest Time as blank and move to the next day as below. Also, the table below shall start from C10.

| Date | Latest Time | Staff ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/05/2023 |  |  |
| 02/05/2023 |  |  |
| 03/05/2023 |  |  |
| 04/05/2023 |  |  |
| 05/05/2023 | 7:08:23 AM | 34564 |
| : | : |  |
| 31/05/2023 |  |  |

This is the code:

```
Sub GetMax()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MaxValue As Date
    Dim DatePart As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim arr
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Update your folder name
    FolderPath = "D:\Temp\"
    ' Clean activesheet and set format
    With ActiveSheet
        .UsedRange.Clear
        .[A1:B1].Value = Array("Date", "LatestTime")
        .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        .Columns(2).NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    End With
    ' Retrieve files with "Workbook_*.xlsx"
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "Workbook_*.xlsx")
    Do While FileName <> ""
        DatePart = Split(FileName, "_")(1)
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
        ' Get max value of column B
        arr = ws.UsedRange.Value
        MaxValue = 0
        If UBound(arr, 2) >= 3 Then
        For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
            If InStr("SYSTEM|VOID", UCase(arr(i, 3))) = 0 Then
                If MaxValue < arr(i, 2) Then MaxValue = arr(i, 2)
            End If
        Next
        End If
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If LastRow > 1 Or .Cells(LastRow, 1) <> "" Then LastRow = LastRow + 1
            .Cells(LastRow, "A").Value = DateSerial(CInt(Mid(DatePart, 1, 4)), CInt(Mid(DatePart, 5, 2)), CInt(Mid(DatePart, 7, 2)))
            .Cells(LastRow, "B").Value = MaxValue
        End With
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

*(Solution from [Compile value from each workbook to main workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76748131/compile-value-from-each-workbook-to-main-workbook/))*

How do I modify the above code if I have an additional column for Contract Date, and wish to filter for Contract Date as well as Staff column?

I wish to filter the Contract Date according to the workbook date.

Note: My data starts on row 3 (row 2 is blank)

| Staff ID | Contract Date | Time | Staff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |
| 34565 | 20230501 | 9:00:35 AM | SYSTEM |
| 23586 | 20230501 | 5:32:05 AM | SYSTEM |
| 46354 | 20230503 | 4:15:35 AM | ALEX |
| 46546 | 20230503 | 4:09:30 AM | CLARE |
| 98744 | 20230504 | 2:54:18 AM | JOHN |
| 34534 | 20230505 | 3:23:10 AM | SANDY |
| 87675 | 20230502 | 4:32:09 AM | MANDA |
| 35645 | 20230505 | 7:15:23 AM | VOID |
| 23423 | 20230505 | 6:15:23 AM | ALEX |
| 23423 | 20230501 | 3:46:15 AM | KEN |
| 34564 | 20230501 | 7:08:23 AM | KEAT |

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the code based on the new requirements. Multiple lines have been modified. Dictionary object is used to store the maxvlue.

```vb
Sub GetMax()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MaxValue As Date
    Dim DatePart As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim arr, dic, rngRes As Range
    Set dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Update your folder name
    FolderPath = "D:\Temp\"
    ' Retrieve files with "Workbook_*.xlsx"
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "Workbook_*.xlsx")
    Do While FileName <> ""
        DatePart = Split(Split(FileName, "_")(1), ".")(0)
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
        ' Get data from worksheet
        arr = ws.UsedRange.Value
        MaxValue = 0
        If UBound(arr, 2) >= 3 Then
            For i = 3 To UBound(arr) ' Start from row 3
                ' filter Data and Staff
                If InStr("SYSTEM|VOID", UCase(arr(i, 4))) = 0 And _
                    CStr(arr(i, 2)) = DatePart Then
                    arr(i, 3) = CDate(arr(i, 3))
                    If MaxValue < arr(i, 3) Then MaxValue = arr(i, 3)
                End If
            Next
        End If
        ' store MaxValue in Dictionary
        dic(DatePart) = MaxValue
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngRes = .Range("C10:D" & LastRow)
        rngRes.Columns(2).NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
        arr = rngRes.Value
        For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
            If VBA.IsDate(arr(i, 1)) Then
                DatePart = Format(arr(i, 1), "yyyymmdd")
                If dic.exists(DatePart) Then
                    arr(i, 2) = dic(DatePart)
                Else
                    arr(i, 2) = ""
                End If
            End If
        Next
        rngRes.Value = arr
    End With
    Set dic = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: what if my dates have been pre-filled and I just want to fill in the Latest Time according to the dates? if there is no workbook for that day, I just want to leave a blank cell. Also, how do I make the table start from C10? @taller_ExcelHome

Comment: It is helpful for us to figure it out if you could update your post and give more detail. e.g. which part data is 'prefilled'? what does 'latest time" mean? The code is looking for lastest time in the 3rd column.

Comment: I have updated my post as above. You may have a look @taller_ExcelHome

Comment: what if I want to record the Staff ID as well? Updated the table as above @taller_ExcelHome

Comment: Hi @taller, was wondering how to modify the code if I want to record the Staff ID as well? Currently, it displays the Date and Latest Time only.

Comment: [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Comment: could you help with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78179076/compile-data-based-on-fixed-column-values @taller