# Compile data based on fixed column values

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple workbooks for each date of the month e.g. Workbook_20230505 with data as below:

| Staff ID | Contract Date | Time | Name | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Blank) |  |  |  |  |
| 80001 | 20230501 | 9:00:35 AM | SYSTEM | A |
| 80002 | 20230501 | 5:32:05 AM | SYSTEM | A |
| 80003 | 20230503 | 4:15:35 AM | ALEX | A |
| 80004 | 20230503 | 4:09:30 AM | CLARE | B |
| 80005 | 20230504 | 2:54:18 AM | JOHN | C |
| 80006 | 20230505 | 3:23:10 AM | SANDY | D |
| 80007 | 20230502 | 4:32:09 AM | MANDA | C |
| 80008 | 20230505 | 7:15:23 AM | VOID | F |
| 80009 | 20230505 | 6:15:23 AM | ALEX | A |
| 80010 | 20230501 | 3:46:15 AM | KEN | B |
| 80011 | 20230501 | 7:08:23 AM | SYSTEM | B |

eg. Workbook_20230506 with data as below:

| Staff ID | Contract Date | Time | Name | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Blank) |  |  |  |  |
| 90001 | 20230503 | 3:00:35 AM | SYSTEM | A |
| 90002 | 20230504 | 11:32:05 AM | SYSTEM | A |
| 90003 | 20230508 | 1:15:30 AM | ALEX | C |
| 90004 | 20230519 | 3:09:32 AM | CLARE | B |
| 90005 | 20230523 | 1:33:18 AM | SYSTEM | C |
| 90006 | 20230522 | 3:26:10 AM | SANDY | A |
| 90007 | 20230521 | 4:32:09 AM | MANDA | A |
| 90008 | 20230522 | 7:15:45 AM | SYSTEM | A |
| 90009 | 20230504 | 6:18:12 AM | ALEX | A |
| 90010 | 20230503 | 3:46:15 AM | SYSTEM | B |
| 90011 | 20230529 | 7:04:22 AM | SYSTEM | B |

This is the intended outcome in a new workbook for compilation:

| Date | Latest Time | Staff ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/05/2023 |  |  |
| 02/05/2023 |  |  |
| 03/05/2023 |  |  |
| 04/05/2023 |  |  |
| 05/05/2023 |  |  |
| : | : |  |
| 31/05/2023 |  |  |

I have the following code:
(obtains the latest time and staff ID given **Name** is System or Alex and **Group** is A)

```
    Sub GetMax()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MaxValue As Date
    Dim MaxID As String
    Dim DatePart As String
    Dim StaffID As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim arr, dic, rngRes As Range

    Set dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Update your folder name
    FolderPath = "D:\Temp\"
    ' Retrieve files with "Workbook_*.xlsx"
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "Workbook_*.xlsx")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    Do While FileName <> ""
        DatePart = Split(FileName, "_")(1)
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
        ' Get max value of column C and value from column A
        arr = ws.UsedRange.Value
        MaxValue = 0
    MaxID = 0
        If UBound(arr, 2) >= 3 Then
            For i = 3 To UBound(arr) 'start from row 3
                    If InStr("SYSTEM|ALEX", UCase(arr(i, 4))) = 0 And _
                InStr("A", UCase(arr(i, 5))) = 0 And _
                CStr(arr(i,2)) = DatePart Then
                arr(i,3) = cDate(arr(i,3))
                            If MaxValue < arr(i, 3) Then MaxValue = arr(i, 3): MaxID = arr(i,1)
            End If
            Next
        End If

    'store MaxValue in Dictionary
    dic(DatePart) = MaxValue
    dic(StaffID) = MaxID
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        FileName = Dir
    Loop

    With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngRes = .Range("B17:D" & LastRow)
    rngRes.Columns(2).NumberFormat = "h:mm"
    arr = rngRes.Value
    For i = 2 to UBound(arr)
        If VBA.IsDate(arr(i,1)) Then
            DatePart = Format(arr(i,1), "yyyymmdd")
            If dic.exists(DatePart) Then
                arr(i,2) = dic(DatePart): arr(i,3) = dic(StaffID)
            Else
                arr(i,2) = ""
            End If
        End If
    Next
    rngRes.Value = arr
    End With
    Set dic = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Which gives the following result:

| Date | Latest Time | Staff ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/05/2023 |  |  |
| 02/05/2023 |  |  |
| 03/05/2023 |  |  |
| 04/05/2023 |  |  |
| 05/05/2023 | 9:00:35 | 90002 |
| 06/05/2023 | 11:32:05 | 90002 |
| : | : |  |
| 31/05/2023 |  |  |

This is the intended outcome:
[image]

The code is unable to input the Staff ID correctly as it displays the same Staff ID from the latest iteration for all dates.

Appreciate the help to correct the code for any mistakes!

*FYI, this is a follow up question from
[Filter on multiple columns and compile value to main workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76780065/filter-on-multiple-columns-and-compile-value-to-main-workbook/76780840#76780840)
Sorry for asking so many times.*

Comment: For the first is it a typo `Set rngRes = .Range(B17:D" & LastRow)` ? It should be `Set rngRes = .Range("B17:D" & LastRow)`

Comment: `DatePart = Split(FileName, "_")(1)` would give you (eg) `20230505.xlsx`...

Comment: Also where do you ever populate `StaffID` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams  the maxID is stored in the dictionary, StaffID as per dic(StaffID) = MaxID. Sorry my coding knowledge is not so good

Comment: There's no point in your code where you assign any value to `StaffID` though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `DatePart = Split(FileName, "_")(1)` doesn't extract date from file name. eg. if filename is `Workbook_20230505.xlsx` then `DatePart` is `20230505.xlsx`.
- `InStr("SYSTEM|ALEX", UCase(arr(i, 4))) = 0` means  `UCase(arr(i, 4))` is NOT SYSTEM or ALEX.
- The 2nd condition equals to `"A" = UCase(arr(i, 5))`.
- The 3rd condition should be removed.

```
If InStr("SYSTEM|ALEX", UCase(arr(i, 4))) = 0 And _
                InStr("A", UCase(arr(i, 5))) = 0 And _
                CStr(arr(i,2)) = DatePart Then
```

- `store MaxValue in Dictionary` section is incorrect. You need to use an array to store multiple values in the Dict object.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [InStr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008946)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub GetMax()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MaxValue As Date
    Dim MaxID As String
    Dim DatePart As String
    Dim StaffID As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim arr, dic, rngRes As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Set dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Update your folder name
    FolderPath = "D:\Temp\"
    ' Retrieve files with "Workbook_*.xlsx"
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "Workbook_*.xlsx")
    Do While FileName <> ""
        DatePart = Split(Replace(FileName, "Workbook_", ""), ".")(0)
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
        ' Get max value of column C and value from column A
        arr = ws.UsedRange.Value
        MaxValue = 0
        MaxID = 0
        If UBound(arr, 2) >= 3 Then
            For i = 3 To UBound(arr) 'start from row 3
                If InStr("SYSTEM|ALEX", UCase(arr(i, 4))) > 0 And "A" = UCase(arr(i, 5)) Then
                    arr(i, 3) = CDate(arr(i, 3))
                    If MaxValue < arr(i, 3) Then MaxValue = arr(i, 3): MaxID = arr(i, 1)
                End If
            Next
        End If
        'store MaxValue in Dictionary
        dic(DatePart) = Array(MaxValue, MaxID)
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngRes = .Range("B17:D" & LastRow)
         ' modify time format as needed
        rngRes.Columns(2).NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss"
        arr = rngRes.Value
        For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
            If VBA.IsDate(arr(i, 1)) Then
                DatePart = Format(arr(i, 1), "yyyymmdd")
                If dic.exists(DatePart) Then
                    arr(i, 2) = dic(DatePart)(0)
                    arr(i, 3) = dic(DatePart)(1)
                Else
                    arr(i, 2) = ""
                    arr(i, 3) = ""
                End If
            End If
        Next
        rngRes.Value = arr
    End With
    Set dic = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```