# Compile value from different columns to main workbook

Tags: excel, vba

*(This is a follow up for: [Filter on multiple columns and compile value to main workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76780065/filter-on-multiple-columns-and-compile-value-to-main-workbook/76780840?noredirect=1#comment137514291_76780840))*

I have multiple workbooks for each date e.g. Workbook_20230505 with data as below:

| Staff ID | Time | Staff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 34565 | 9:00:35 AM | SYSTEM |
| 23586 | 5:32:05 AM | SYSTEM |
| 46354 | 4:15:35 AM | ALEX |
| 46546 | 4:09:30 AM | CLARE |
| 98744 | 2:54:18 AM | JOHN |
| 34534 | 3:23:10 AM | SANDY |
| 87675 | 4:32:09 AM | MANDA |
| 35645 | 7:15:23 AM | VOID |
| 23423 | 6:15:23 AM | ALEX |
| 23423 | 3:46:15 AM | KEN |
| 34564 | 7:08:23 AM | KEAT |

I have a code which compiles the latest time given criteria (where Staff <> "SYSTEM" or "VOID") to a main workbook as below:

| Date | Latest Time |
| --- | --- |
| 01/05/2023 |  |
| 02/05/2023 |  |
| 03/05/2023 |  |
| 04/05/2023 |  |
| 05/05/2023 | 7:08:23 AM |
| : | : |
| 31/05/2023 |  |

This is the code:

```
Sub GetMax()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MaxValue As Date
    Dim DatePart As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim arr
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Update your folder name
    FolderPath = "D:\Temp\"
    ' Clean activesheet and set format
    With ActiveSheet
        .UsedRange.Clear
        .[A1:B1].Value = Array("Date", "LatestTime")
        .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        .Columns(2).NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    End With
    ' Retrieve files with "Workbook_*.xlsx"
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "Workbook_*.xlsx")
    Do While FileName <> ""
        DatePart = Split(FileName, "_")(1)
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
        ' Get max value of column B
        arr = ws.UsedRange.Value
        MaxValue = 0
        If UBound(arr, 2) >= 3 Then
        For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
            If InStr("SYSTEM|VOID", UCase(arr(i, 3))) = 0 Then
                If MaxValue < arr(i, 2) Then MaxValue = arr(i, 2)
            End If
        Next
        End If
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If LastRow > 1 Or .Cells(LastRow, 1) <> "" Then LastRow = LastRow + 1
            .Cells(LastRow, "A").Value = DateSerial(CInt(Mid(DatePart, 1, 4)), CInt(Mid(DatePart, 5, 2)), CInt(Mid(DatePart, 7, 2)))
            .Cells(LastRow, "B").Value = MaxValue
        End With
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

*(Solution from [Compile value from each workbook to main workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76748131/compile-value-from-each-workbook-to-main-workbook/))*

How can I modify the above to record the staff ID as well?

| Date | Latest Time | Staff ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/05/2023 |  |  |
| 02/05/2023 |  |  |
| 03/05/2023 |  |  |
| 04/05/2023 |  |  |
| 05/05/2023 |  |  |
| : | : |  |
| 31/05/2023 |  |  |

Appreciate the help!

Comment: What have you tried so far yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this mod

```
Sub GetMax()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MaxValue As Date
    Dim MaxName As String            'added
    Dim DatePart As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim arr
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Update your folder name
    FolderPath = "D:\Temp\"
    ' Clean activesheet and set format
    With ActiveSheet
        .UsedRange.Clear
        .[A1:B1].Value = Array("Date", "LatestTime")
        .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        .Columns(2).NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    End With
    ' Retrieve files with "Workbook_*.xlsx"
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "Workbook_*.xlsx")
    Do While FileName <> ""
        DatePart = Split(FileName, "_")(1)
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
        ' Get max value of column B
        arr = ws.UsedRange.Value
        MaxValue = 0
        If UBound(arr, 2) >= 3 Then
        For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
            If InStr("SYSTEM|VOID", UCase(arr(i, 3))) = 0 Then
                If MaxValue < arr(i, 2) Then MaxValue = arr(i, 2): MaxName = arr(i, 3)         'edited
            End If
        Next
        End If
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If LastRow > 1 Or .Cells(LastRow, 1) <> "" Then LastRow = LastRow + 1
            .Cells(LastRow, "A").Value = DateSerial(CInt(Mid(DatePart, 1, 4)), CInt(Mid(DatePart, 5, 2)), CInt(Mid(DatePart, 7, 2)))
            .Cells(LastRow, "B").Value = MaxValue
            .Cells(LastRow, "C").Value = MaxName       'added
        End With
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```