# How to compile data based on fixed column values

Tags: excel, vba

*(This is a follow up for: [Compile value from different columns to main workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78016365/compile-value-from-different-columns-to-main-workbook))*

I have multiple workbooks for each date e.g. Workbook_20230505 with data as below:

| Staff ID | Time | Staff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 34565 | 9:00:35 AM | SYSTEM |
| 23586 | 5:32:05 AM | SYSTEM |
| 46354 | 4:15:35 AM | ALEX |
| 46546 | 4:09:30 AM | CLARE |
| 98744 | 2:54:18 AM | JOHN |
| 34534 | 3:23:10 AM | SANDY |
| 87675 | 4:32:09 AM | MANDA |
| 35645 | 7:15:23 AM | VOID |
| 23423 | 6:15:23 AM | ALEX |
| 23423 | 3:46:15 AM | KEN |
| 34564 | 7:08:23 AM | KEAT |

I have a code which compiles data as per below:

| Date | Latest Time | Staff ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/05/2023 |  |  |
| 02/05/2023 |  |  |
| 03/05/2023 |  |  |
| 04/05/2023 |  |  |
| 05/05/2023 |  |  |
| : | : |  |
| 31/05/2023 |  |  |

This is the code:

```
Sub GetMax()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MaxValue As Date
    Dim DatePart As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim arr
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Update your folder name
    FolderPath = "D:\Temp\"
    ' Clean activesheet and set format
    With ActiveSheet
        .UsedRange.Clear
        .[A1:B1].Value = Array("Date", "LatestTime")
        .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        .Columns(2).NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    End With
    ' Retrieve files with "Workbook_*.xlsx"
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "Workbook_*.xlsx")
    Do While FileName <> ""
        DatePart = Split(FileName, "_")(1)
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
        ' Get max value of column B
        arr = ws.UsedRange.Value
        MaxValue = 0
        If UBound(arr, 2) >= 3 Then
        For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
            If InStr("SYSTEM|VOID", UCase(arr(i, 3))) = 0 Then
                If MaxValue < arr(i, 2) Then MaxValue = arr(i, 2)
            End If
        Next
        End If
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If LastRow > 1 Or .Cells(LastRow, 1) <> "" Then LastRow = LastRow + 1
            .Cells(LastRow, "A").Value = DateSerial(CInt(Mid(DatePart, 1, 4)), CInt(Mid(DatePart, 5, 2)), CInt(Mid(DatePart, 7, 2)))
            .Cells(LastRow, "B").Value = MaxValue
        End With
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**How to modify the code if I pre-list all dates of the month from cell C17, so that it just compiles the latest time and staff ID? (to leave blank time and staff ID if data is not available for a certain date)**

Appreciate the help!

Comment: You've posted the wrong code. You need to post the answer you got when asking your previous question. Also, `i` isn't declared (`Dim i As Long`). Use `Option Explicit` at the top of each module so this doesn't happen when it might be important.

Answer (score 0):

### Import Max Data

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ImportMaxData()
    
    Const SRC_FOLDER_PATH = "D:\Temp\"
    Const SRC_FILE_NAME_LEFT As String = "Workbook_"
    Const SRC_FILE_NAME_RIGHT_DATE_FORMAT As String = "yyyymmdd"
    Const SRC_FILE_EXTENSION As String = ".xlsx"
    Const SRC_SHEET_ID As Variant = 1
    Const SRC_FIRST_DATA_ROW As Long = 3
    Const SRC_MIN_COLUMNS_COUNT As Long = 3
    Const SRC_NOT_CRITERIA As String = "System|Void"
    
    Const DST_TIME_FORMAT As String = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    Const DST_STAFF_FORMAT As String = "@"
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
        
    Dim drg As Range, dlData() As Variant, drCount As Long
    
    With dws.UsedRange
        drCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        With .Resize(drCount).Offset(1) ' exclude headers
            dlData = .Columns("A").Value
            Set drg = .Columns("B:C")
        End With
    End With
    
    Dim drData As Variant: ReDim drData(1 To drCount, 1 To 2)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim swb As Workbook, sws As Worksheet, sData As Variant
    Dim sr As Long, sFilePath As String, sFileName As String
    Dim MaxValue As Variant, MaxStaffID As Variant, sName As String
    Dim IsValidFileFound As Boolean, HasEnoughColumns As Boolean
    
    Dim dr As Long
    
    For dr = 1 To drCount
        ' Check if (date) file exists.
        If IsDate(dlData(dr, 1)) Then
            sFilePath = SRC_FOLDER_PATH & SRC_FILE_NAME_LEFT _
                & Format(dlData(dr, 1), SRC_FILE_NAME_RIGHT_DATE_FORMAT) _
                & SRC_FILE_EXTENSION
            sFileName = Dir(sFilePath)
            If Len(sFileName) > 0 Then IsValidFileFound = True
        End If
        ' Open file and check if enough columns!?
        If IsValidFileFound Then
            Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath, , True)
            Set sws = swb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_ID)
            sData = sws.UsedRange.Value
            swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            If UBound(sData, 2) >= SRC_MIN_COLUMNS_COUNT Then
                HasEnoughColumns = True
            End If
        End If
        ' Write max to destination array.
        If HasEnoughColumns Then
            For sr = SRC_FIRST_DATA_ROW To UBound(sData, 1)
                sName = CStr(sData(sr, 3))
                If InStr(1, SRC_NOT_CRITERIA, sName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    If IsNumeric(sData(sr, 2)) Then
                        If MaxValue < sData(sr, 2) Then
                            MaxValue = sData(sr, 2)
                            MaxStaffID = sData(sr, 1)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next sr
            drData(dr, 1) = MaxValue
            drData(dr, 2) = MaxStaffID
        End If
        ' Reset for the next iteration.
        MaxValue = 0
        MaxStaffID = 0
        HasEnoughColumns = False
        IsValidFileFound = False
    Next dr
    
    ' Write result and format.
    With drg
        .Columns(1).NumberFormat = DST_TIME_FORMAT
        .Columns(2).NumberFormat = DST_STAFF_FORMAT
        .Value = drData
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Max data imported.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: How can I modify the above if I wish the add additional criteria from a different column number eg. 6? Also, how to modify so that my table begins at cell B17 instead of A1?